# How can I keep the selection active state of a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

In this quiz selection component I put two different div bootstrap list-group with buttons.
I'd like to keep the active class when I click on some button but only one of them inside each div can be active.
So for example if I click on "History" and then "Medium", I'd like them to keep active class.

I've tried to add some bootstrap 4 options like "Active state" and tried to toggle active class onClick.
But in this way active class still stay in each button I click.

Thank you very much for help

```
class Selection extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="border rounded w-75 mx-auto">
        <div className="row pt-4">
          <div className="col-6">
            <div
              onClick={this.props.chooseCategory}
              className="list-group w-75 ml-auto"
            >
              <p>Choose a category</p>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" active
              >
                Mix
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
              >
                Sports
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
              >
                History
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
              >
                Movies
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
              >
                Geography
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-6">
            <div
              className="list-group w-50 mr-auto"
              onClick={this.props.chooseDifficulty}
            >
              <p>Choose the difficulty</p>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="list-group-item list-group-item-action active"
              >
                Easy
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
              >
                Medium
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
              >
                Hard
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          onClick={this.props.handleStart}
          className="btn btn-outline-primary my-4"
        >
          START
        </button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add state to the component, to represent the actively selected category and difficulty.

i.e. (in constructor)
    `this.state = { category: 'Mix', difficulty: 'Easy' }`

Later in the render function you can check, using an if or inline ternary statement. I would also create an array representing the options and use array.map() to shorten your code.

```
const categoryOptions = [ 'Mix', 'Sports', 'History']
```

(in render function, instead of manually adding all those buttons...)

```
{ categoryOptions.map(category => (
    <button
         type="button"
         className={`list-group-item list-group-item-action $(this.state.category === category ? 'active' : '')`}
         onClick=(() => this.setState({category: category}))
    >
    {category}
    </button>
)) }
```

The onClick will alter the state to represent the active element, the active class will conditionally be shown, only when that category has been selected.

I don't want to take this answer too far astray, but a further enhancement would be using the React useState hook with functional components, from the latest version of React.

Comment: onClick=( () => this.setState({category: category}) ) should be onClick={ () => this.setState({category: category})  } but upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

use state to show the active div elements

onClick of the div make the state active as true

```
<div>
{this.state.active ? <div><button1><div> : <div><button2></div>}
</div>
```